# SQL server 2008 encrypted connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, certificate, windows-server-2008

I've created and installed a self-signed certificate `test` on my Windows 2008 Server. I've set `Force Encryption` to `Yes` and set the certificate to `test`.

I've exported and sent the `test` certificate to clients. They've installed it to the Trusted Authority store. They've tried to connect to the SQL server through the SQL Management Studio Express, with the `Encrypt connection` set. They get the following error:

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)**

Note that they can connect to the server just fine through unencrypted connection and settings.

I've tried most solutions thrown out by google about this error, but I don't think any of them dealt with encryption.

I've also tried [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic611829-146-1.aspx) method, but I still get the same error.

I don't have the `Primary DNS Suffix` set, if that has any affect on certificates?

EDIT: My goal is to somehow have an encrypted connection from remote computers to my databse, because my clients demand it. We were considering VPN, but there is no need for it, if this can be done on SQL server.

EDIT 2: The certificate "Issued" fields are set to local domain name (that's not resolvable by remote computers). Could this be an issue? Can I somehow set the certificate to an external IP address, if that'll fix the issue?

Comment: The certificate should contain the server host name in the Common Name attribute. If the host name is different from the clients perspective then the client should not continue. Maybe this is the issue? Sometimes you can get better error indication by simply connecting with a browser and specifying `"https"` and the correct port adres from the client.

Comment: PS so in short, yes, the DNS settings could screw up the SSL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

owlstead (in the comments) was right. I had to set the `Computer name` to the domain name and the `Primary DNS Suffix` to the subdomain name.